# Displaying i18n text on HTML-button depending on condition Aurelia

Tags: html, aurelia

Hi I am trying to dynamically change a text depending on a boolean.
Im using Aurelia with i18n, one solution would be to just have a method that returns what you want. But I would like to have it in the html, because I think its clearer to see which text the button will have depending on the bool in the html code.
This is what it looks like now:

```
<button>${account.changed ? '_cancel' | t : '_close' | t } </button>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
<button>${account.changed ? ('_cancel' | t) : ('_close' | t) } </button>
<button>${account.changed ? ${'_cancel' | t} : ${'_close' | t} } </button>
```

Any of my tries ends with a crash:

```
Error: Parser Error: Conditional expression account.changed ? '_cancel'  requires all 3 expressions at column 33 in [account.changed ? '_cancel' | t : '_close' | t ]
```

I have only used i18N like this to this point:

```
<div>${'example | t'}</div>
```

Never needed to change the text depending on a condition before.

**To anyone that comes here, I solved this doing this:**

```
innerHTML.bind="!account.changed ? close  : cancel"
```

and in the .js

```
   this.close = this.i18n.tr('_close');
   this.cancel = this.i18n.tr('_cancel');
```

I do think it should be possible in some way to achive this directly in HTML with aurelia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I'm using:

```
<span t="_cancel" if.bind="account.changed"></span><span t="_close" if.bind="!account.changed"></span>
```

I was stuck on this for a while and this is the best way I found to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the parser currently doesn't support nested expressions. In the mean time, you could use some trickery like:

```
<button ref="myButton" cancel-text="${'_cancel' | t}" close-text="${'_close' | t}">${account.changed ? myButton.cancelText : myButton.closeText}</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at how ValueConverters work in Aurelia you will see they leverage the pipe symbol. This works as you'd expect from classic unix style pipes where the left expressions output is forwarded to the next thing after the pipe.

So your solution should be like this:

```
<button>${account.changed ? '_cancel' : '_close' | t }</button>
```

First determine the proper string using the shorthand if syntax and the result of that gets passed on to the TValueConverter.